# Prove that the Klein group $V_4$ is isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I'm really struggling trying to prove that the Klein group $V_4$  is isomorphic to $C_2\times C_2$. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What definition of the Klein four group are you using?

Comment: Definition: additive group of the field with four elements

Comment: I'm glad I asked. That is not exactly a standard definition.

Comment: Pretty much any bijection will do, as long as you are careful to send the identity to the identity! Did you even try one?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Table for $V_4$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
*& e & a & b & c \\ \hline
e & e&a&b&c\\ \hline
a & a& e&c&b\\ \hline
b & b& c&e&a\\ \hline
c & c& b& a& e \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Table for $C_2\times C_2$

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
+& (0,0) & (0,1) & (1,0) & (1,1) \\ \hline
(0,0) &(0,0)&(0,1)&(1,0)&(1,1)\\ \hline
(0,1) & (0,1)&(0,0)&(1,1)&(1,0)\\ \hline
(1,0) &(1,0)&(1,1)&(0,0)&(0,1)\\ \hline
(1,1) & (1,1)&(1,0)&(0,1)&(0,0) \\ \hline
\end{array}$$